# Apply own function across vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using a dataframe as a lookup table. Given the name of an financial institution (FI) return its ID.

I have a function that can do that for a single (FI) at a time. I wish to use this function with a vector of a few dozen FIs.

So feeding `companies` into the function should return 12 and 14.

Is this a job for the Tidyverse map function?

```
library("tidyverse")

groups_df <- tibble(
  fi = c("a", "b", "c"),
  id = c(10, 12, 14)
)
companies <- c("b", "c")

group_id_lookup <- function(new_comp, groups_df){
  group_id_idx <- which(groups_df$fi == new_comp)
  group_id <- pull(groups_df[group_id_idx, 2])
  print(group_id)
  # Do more things
}


group_id_lookup("b", groups_df) # OK
group_id_lookup("c", groups_df) # OK

# Wrong
companies %>% 
  map(group_id_lookup)
```

Comment: You didn't pass `groups_df` to your map. Try `companies %>% map(group_id_lookup, groups_df)`. But in general this type of operation would be better accomplished by a `left_join` (or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join or `match` option should be a better approach here.

```
groups_df$id[match(companies, groups_df$fi)]
#[1] 12 14
```